# Eclipse stops running reason = "breakpoint"

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am working with eclipse using C++.  It was working fine till yesterday. Now when I use break points and debug I get a stopped,reason="breakpoint-hit" error and then eclipse stops.  Has anyone seen this error and anyone know how to fix it?

I have used breakpoints before to help me debug.  Instead of the step into, step over, and step out options, Eclipse stops running.  I am not doing anything out of the usual with breakpoints, I tried them at several different points and got the same problem.

Comment: Well, that's what breakpoints are for: to stop your program.

Comment: Question: why did you use breakpoints?

Comment: @Chris, My program doesn't pause like when I normally use breakpoints. My program dies.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse obviously has problems with debugging while you use the console for typing in input. Is that your case? I had that problem and while googling for a solution, I finally came upon a recommendation that while debugging, you should pass input to your program from a file rather than typing it to the console.

The recommendation can be found here:
http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/234122/Spring2011/en/faq_Working%20with%20Eclipse%20CDT.html
(It's the question that starts with "I have a problem with debugging in Eclipse.".)

Hope this helps.